# Aligning 2 spans together for animation to happen on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit, css-animations

http://jsfiddle.net/StNm8/

```
<section class="first">
        <div class="welcome">
        <div>
        <span class="greet">
        Hello Fellas, Want to get an Excellent Quality Service
        </span>
        <span class="bounce">?</span> 

        </div>
        <p class="showThem">
        You are at the right place !
        </p>
        </div>
        </section>
```

This is the CSS:-

```
.first {
    background-color: #d8262e;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 40;
    text-align: center;

}
.welcome{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 75%;
    /* margin:75px auto 0; */

}
.greet, .bounce{
    color: white;
      /* display:block;  */ 

      /* float:left; */  
    font: 900 4.688em/1.2em "Times",sans-serif;


}
.greet{
    float:left;
}
.bounce{
    display:block;
}
.bounce::after{
    clear: both;
} 

.showThem{
    color:white;
    display: block;
    font:900 4.688em/1.2em "Karla",sans-serif;
}

.showThem:before{
    clear:both;
}

.bounce{
      -webkit-animation: bounceAnimate 350ms linear 0s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: bounceAnimate 350ms linear  0s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: bounceAnimate 350ms linear  0s infinite alternate;
    animation: bounceAnimate 350ms linear  0s infinite alternate;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceAnimate{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0em,0em,0em);  
    }
    50%{
         -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0em,0em,0em);
    }
}

@keyframes bounceAnimate{
    from{
        transform: translate3d(0em,0em,0em);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: translate3d(0em,0em,0em);
    } 

}
```

I'm facing a problem while trying to align the 2 spans - greet and bounce together in a single line.
The greet span is acting as a block and because of that the text in the 'bounce' span is appearing in the next line. I intend to see both the content of 'greet' and 'bounce' in the same line.

What I've tried at my end:-

I have tried to put the 'bounce' span in a paragraph and give `class=greet`to that paragraph as in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usLnG/1/, but, then, my animation does not run on Firefox and Safari

So, I would request you to guide me out of this problem.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make this <span> staying at the end of the paragraph without placing it inside <p> tag. However have you tried adding -moz-transform version of animation to your CSS?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that as well. It is not working still. please have a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/usLnG/5/

Comment: Well, with this fiddle and Firefox animation of this `<span>` doesn't work inside and outside `<p>` as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.bounce` to `{display:inline-block;}` and delete `.greet{float:left;}`. Making `.greet` float to the left is removing it from the normal document flow.

[Code JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StNm8/1)

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StNm8/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:inline-block` to the `.bounce` class solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/usLnG/5/

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I want to animate the question mark while it is aligned in the same line as the text of the `class=greet`

Comment: That's exactly what I get with this fiddle in Firefox. Try expanding result area on JSFiddle, its default size makes the question mark being placed under the rest of the text. You can also delete a space between "Service" and `<span>` to be sure that it won't be behaving like this. ; )